# Writing vertex to OrientDB with gremlin-scala wrapper

Tags: scala, orientdb, tinkerpop3, orientdb-2.1, tinkerpop-blueprint

I'm using `"com.michaelpollmeier" %% "gremlin-scala" % "3.2.0.1"` together with `"com.michaelpollmeier" % "orientdb-gremlin" % "3.2.0-incubating.1-SNAPSHOT"` to store some domain objects as Vertices to an OrientDB (v2.1.20)

I understand it's pretty bleeding edge code but I'd like some pointers to understand why is the driver throwing this exception:

> Caused by:
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Error
>   on deserialization of Serializable    at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.binary.OSerializableWrapper.fromStream(OSerializableWrapper.java:47)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.binary.ORecordSerializerBinaryV0.readSingleValue(ORecordSerializerBinaryV0.java:382)
>     ... 13 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.esc.domain.Address

Any hint would be very much appreciated as to what's going on :)

Best,
Edoardo

Answer (score 1):

Eventually found the cause (see [github issue](https://github.com/mpollmeier/orientdb-gremlin/issues/82) about it) in the Scala macro used in gremlin-scala to convert a case class to a Vertex prior to saving it. In short it doesn't recur into member case class instances and sends whatever is there.

Solution is to forego the macro and implement a custom `gremlin.scala.Marshallable[YourCC]`